# Is date safe in encrypted phone without passcode

Tags: security, data-recovery, encryption, password, password-protection

If my phone does not have a passcode, but is encrypted by default, and I factory reset it, is my data safe? Or is there a way someone can decrypt it since it had no passcode

Comment: If no password is set [`default_password`](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/system/vold/+/refs/tags/android-11.0.0_r1/cryptfs.cpp#279) is your password which is used to derive keys used for encryption. With factory reset they should be gone and cannot be recovered.